# Android SIGSEGV exception at startup of application

Tags: android, c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I have problem with my application that I have made in QT Necessitas for android.

I am using my application on desktop PC and everything is working fine but when I use it on android I get error : `0xafd15ca4  <+0x0058>         strb   r0, [r1, #0]` at `_libc_android_abort and get error about SIGSEGV error.

I can't trace where my code is starting I have debugger houndred times but still can't find it. Maybe problem is in my app. I am loading data from PHP script into my phone memory. But honestly I have like 6 contacts from database which I get as result. So I don't think it should be problem.

Any idea? and please help me how to trace error or something.

Comment: When I ran into this with my app it was due to a null pointer down in native. Hard to trace, I had to rewrite my app to use an update thread, and do my work there to avoid any null pointers.

Comment: I think it is because I am connecting to a server at the startup of the app and probably I can't connect so my pointer stays null. Thank you anyway. I think it is this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.
Problem was null pointer. I was accessing variable which has null pointer because I couldn't make successful connection to database. But connection solved my problem.